# Porch Light replacement

Tags: electrical, porch

We decided to replace the porch lights at the garage. They are connected to a porch light by the front door. We turned the power switch off, my husband installed one light. We turned on switch and the light came on. We then turned the switch off again, he installed the new. I told him the black and white wires were connected wrong. Black to white instead of white to white. He turned the switch on, breaker popped and he said the 2nd light sparked. We then connected the light correctly. There is now no power to the lights. We reset the breaker twice. Checked all (that I’m aware of) GFCI and they are all on. I reset them all. We still have no power to the lights.
Can anyone assist on why or what to do next?
Thank you

Comment: The black to white misalignment is a red herring. You can go black to white and white to black without causing an electrical issue.

Comment: Working on lights and hoping the switch turns off all the power is not smart.  Good chance the power surge of the short loosen a connection somewhere, push in connectors on receptacles/outlets are known for this.  I would turn off the breaker and recheck all wire connections.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the wiring

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @dandavis, yes in hindsight I can see that it was an attempt to help the OP troubleshoot the issue. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

> no power to the lights. Can anyone assist on why or what to do

Usually this means the wires are damaged as a result of incorrect installation.

The circuit breaker must remain off now.

The "2nd light" should be removed and checked for damage.

If the location of the damage isn't obvious, then the next step is to remove and check the switch, the other lights, and other parts of the circuit as necessary.

Comment: "Damage" could simply consist of a poor connection that got blown loose by the short created during the installation of the 2nd light, and not any obviously "broken" thing.